# Import json in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am new to typescript.In my project we are using typescript2, In one of my requirement i need to import json file. so i have created .d.ts file as follows

```
 test.d.ts
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

i have included this definition in my tsconfig.json and importing to my ts file as follows

```
  test.ts
//<refrence path="./test.json"/>
import * as data from './test.json';
```

when i am building my code i am getting following error

```
Cannot find module './test.json'
```

Note:- i don't want to use Requirejs

Thanks

Comment: you will need something like commonjs or systemjs to import files like that

Comment: you can copy the content of JSON into ts file and export that. export const obj={};

Comment: I've added an explicit `/// <reference path="test.d.ts" />` before the import to basically enforce that `test.ts` uses that declaration file. Seems to work for me

Answer (score 19):

With **TypeScript 2.9.+** you can simply import JSON files with typesafety and intellisense like this:

```
import testJson from './test.json';
console.log(testJson.yourPropertyName);
```

Make sure to add these settings to your tsconfig.json:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

If you need the data to be recognised as a specific class, you can do that after import with `as`, for instance:

```
const typedData = testJson as MyType[]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this `testJson[yourPropertyName]`? Typescript is complaining about no index signature.

Comment: @Peracek that's most likely because TypeScript doesn't know `yourPropertyName` is a valid index of the provided JSON, but yes you can extract the type of the JSON structure and then you can use `keyof typeof JSONStructure` to assert it's a valid index

Comment: This answer could be improved by showing an example with context and/or specifying exactly where in `tsconfig.json` those settings should go.

Comment: They should be put on the root level inside of the JSON object

Comment: If you don't want to use `esModuleInterop`, then you can instead use the `import = require` syntax. @kentor, thanks for the `keyof` tip!

Answer (score 2):

I handled that using a .ts with the json data in a variable:

```
import { data } from './jsonData'; // jsonData.ts
```

And the jsonData.ts would be like that:

```
export var data = {
  "key": "value",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following [this great article](https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79) and depending on the TypeScript version you are using, you can follow the other 2 answers.

The case that is missing from them is when you are using TypeScript 2+. In this case, if you have a `json` file like this:

```
{
    "name": "testing"
}
```

you should add the following in the `typings.d.ts` file:

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

And then import the `json` file as follows:

```
import * as data from './example.json';

const word = (<any>data).name;

console.log(word); // output 'testing'
```

Comment: None of these answers work. Something so common as importing JSON should really 'just work' with Typescript. Unfortunately, of course it does not. Like a many things in Typescript.