# Using a Dictionary in a JSON-File

Tags: c#, json, typescript

To create the JSON file, I am using a C# Dictionary:

```
  public Dictionary<int, List<string>> AbsatzNrSaetzeText { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

This will result in [*Sound*.json](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiU5zEgMWxPk-xJ4a-DcxiahZNUm?e=KdwzAM), which I am trying to convert - using http://json2ts.com/ - into a TypeScript data structure.

Which will result in something like this:

```
declare module namespace {

export interface AbsatzNrSaetzeText {
    2: string[];
    3: string[];
    4: string[];
    5: string[];
    6: string[];
    8: string[];
    9: string[];
    10: string[];
    11: string[];
//...
```

But this does not look very smart, because for every `AbsatzNrSaetzeText` or `AbsatzNrSaetzeTextPunkte` entry, the key (from the dictionary) is used. In the end the data structure will look pretty big, confusingly and cluttered.

Is there another solution (please provide a code snippet) to create the data structure in typescript?

Comment: Try using https://app.quicktype.io/?l=ts

Comment: You can also use static TypeScript JSON imports which actually give you full typing for the JSON as if it was in your TypeScript as an `as const` object if that would be easier. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50674365/10873797

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript already has a type for that `Record<K, V>` You can use `Record<number, string[]>` in this case.